# FFMPEG JAVA ffmpeg doesn't work in .jar application

Tags: java, video, ffmpeg, media

FFMPEG works only in developer mode. When I compile my jar program it returns the following error
the log of the program launched with eclipse in this case everything works

```
  ffmpeg version git-2019-12-29-e20c6d9 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9.2.1 (GCC) 20191125
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-sdl2 --enable-fontconfig --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libdav1d --enable-libbluray --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libzimg --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-gmp --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libmysofa --enable-libspeex --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libmfx --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuvid --enable-d3d11va --enable-nvenc --enable-nvdec --enable-dxva2 --enable-avisynth --enable-libopenmpt --enable-amf
  libavutil      56. 38.100 / 56. 38.100
  libavcodec     58. 65.100 / 58. 65.100
  libavformat    58. 35.101 / 58. 35.101
  libavdevice    58.  9.101 / 58.  9.101
  libavfilter     7. 70.100 /  7. 70.100
  libswscale      5.  6.100 /  5.  6.100
  libswresample   3.  6.100 /  3.  6.100
  libpostproc    55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
Input #0, h264, from '.h264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), yuv420p(progressive), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1200k tbn, 120 tbc
Output #0, mp4, to '.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.35.101
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 3840x2160 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 60 fps, 60 tbr, 15360 tbn, 120 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mp4 @ 000001cedad59440] Timestamps are unset in a packet for stream 0. This is deprecated and will stop working in the future. Fix your code to set the timestamps properly
frame= 9273 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=  121326kB time=00:01:17.26 bitrate=12863.3kbits/s speed= 207x    
video:121287kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.032451%
```

This is where it gets complicated. You can observe the messages that FFMPEG returns to me when I launch my program compile in jar :

```
> [h264 @ 0000017c43e5b700] error while decoding MB 58 6, bytestream -14
> [h264 @ 0000017c43e5b700] concealing 30951 DC, 30951 AC, 30951 MV
> errors in I frame [h264 @ 0000017c43e49d80] Stream #0: not enough
> frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize [h264 @
> 0000017c43e49d80] decoding for stream 0 failed
```

This is the java code which thanks to the ProcessBuilder will launch FFMPEG :

```
String urlVideoMp4 = movie.getPath().replace(".h264", ".mp4");

File videoFinal = new File(urlVideoMp4);
//checking if new video exists : if not, creating it with FFMPEG

LOG.info("moviePath : " + movie);
ProcessBuilder processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(FFMPEG, "-framerate", "60", "-r", "120", "-i", movie.getPath(),"-c:v", "copy", urlVideoMp4);
LOG.debug(processBuilder.command());

processBuilder.inheritIO().start().waitFor();

return videoFinal;
```

Comment: I don't know where your issue is coming from, but to my knowledge : you always have to manage files I/O in different ways, depending if you run the project in your IDE or if you run the exported .jar file. Hope it can help you some way !

Comment: can you please share full crash log

Comment: I have no log view since the application does not crash. it is the behavior of FFMPEG which changes.
I have already implemented I / O management